# Processing a Django Form in a Celery Task - How can the celery task see the form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, celery

The use case is rather simple. That of a background transaction manager, which requires that this classic type of post handler:

```py
class MyCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form = self.get_form()

        if self.form.is_valid():
            self.object = self.form.save(commit=True)
            return self.form_valid(self.form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(self.form)
```

doesn't save the form with `form.save()`, but rather saves the form object somewhere (to the session?) starts a Celery task which will then be responsible for running `form.save()`

The problem I'm facing is that the form object is refusing to serialize at all, with JSON or pickle, it's just too rich an object, and starting a Celery task requires the arguments to be serialized. I can serialize just the POST data `(request.POST)` which is doable, and pass it to the Celery task as an argument which works but I can't from that find any way to re-instantiate a form, let alone a `formset`.

if I want to start the Celery task from a view I redirect to (that implements a progress bar say) then I have the even bigger challenge of passing the form to a whole new Django view. The obvious candidate is to save it to session:

```py
self.request.session["my_form_data"] = self.request.POST
```

But then in the Celery task, I can't even load that session data (I can possibly wrangle it using [out of view sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views)), or in the view load, it then passes it as an argument.

The aim though is that the Celery task has a Form object that we can call the save() method on, from the posted data, and generally manage and manipulate as we do a Form. One possibility is to instantiate a ModelForm using the POST data as Initial data then saving that but that's not obviously a solution and may or may not work.

In short, I'm trying to recreate a small part of the view context inside a Celery task, and given how often I see Django and Celery mentioned on-line together (and they seem to work well together) I'm really wondering before I experiment this to death with a hacked up solution, if there are not some simple or canonical means of doing this that I am missing.

I see hints of solutions all over the place. There is the [django-remote-forms](https://github.com/WiserTogether/django-remote-forms) which promises to serialize a form but offers no means of recreating a Form object or objects (given we maybe use FormSets) from such serialized data. And there's the hint of a FormSerializer in the [Django REST framework](https://django-rest-framework-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html), but that's a big bundle of package and learning with lots of baggage that may not even do what I need by the time I'm done.

There's even good documentation of [serializing Django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/), but not Forms.

It would be a dream if there was a simple, canonical method of passing a Django Form object to a Celery Task so it can work with it just as the Django view might.